# bandwidthTest gives results in binary MB/s?

Tags: cuda, bandwidth

My understanding of memory bandwidth is that it is reported using the `SI units`, `kilo=10^3`, `mega=10^6 etc` (although memory size is obviously reported in 2^n format).

The CUDA bandwidthTest sample seems to flaunt this. The below sample is straight from the SDK sample, where memSize is an integer describing the size of the array and is 32*2^20 by default and MEMCOPY_ITERATIONS is an integer.

Let's say elapsed time is 1000ms and MEMCOPY_ITERATIONS=1, the results would be 64MB/s, but the MB is of the form 2^20. Is my assumption correct, and if so is the binary notation of bandwidth accepted?

I thought it wasn't.

```
//calculate bandwidth in MB/s
bandwidthInMBs = 2.0f * (1e3f * memSize * (float)MEMCOPY_ITERATIONS) /
                 (elapsedTimeInMs * (float)(1 << 20));
```

EDIT: On the off chance that anyone ever searches for this again, an altered bandwidthTest that reports in SI MB/s is [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxtYXJram1hd3NvbnxneDoyODRhMTIxOTIyZjI1YWJm), adapted from the CUDA 5.5 SDK and including the Visual Studio Projects.

Comment: I had a hand in writing this benchmark, and I am kind of old school; to me a "megabyte" will always be 1048576 bytes.

I might be more inclined to use the correct terminology if it were more palatable, I mean, "mebibyte," really?

This issue has gotten more traction as the units get bigger. No one quibbled that the 64K Apple ][ had 536 more bytes of memory than the SI unit would imply, but 1K=1024 bytes is only 2.4% more than 1000.  For MiB/MB and GiB/GB, the differences are 4.9% and 7.3%, respectively.

IMHO anyone looking at benchmarks like this should double-check the units.

Comment: I completely agree with you, a bit of pragmatism when using someone else's code should be standard practice. It has put me in the strange position where I am comparing the bandwidth efficiency of my code against others who have misunderstood the units in bandwidthTest; differences in our code efficiency vs bandwidth are _actually_ negligible, but the 4.9% difference between SI and binary units makes it look like there is a difference. Do you happen to know which units are used the the nsight profiler?

Comment: On the nsight profiler, nope, I do not know what units they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bandwidthTest gives results in binary MB/s?

Yes.

> is the binary notation of bandwidth accepted?

Perhaps not.

(those were the only 2 questions I could find.)

Since the binary megabyte is larger than the SI megabyte, it would seem that the `bandwidthTest` *sample code* is under-reporting if you interpret the results according to SI units.  As a sample code, it's primary purpose is to educate and instruct, not conform to some definition.

You have the source code -- you can make your version of it report any way that you want.

Comment: A fair point. I asked because I have seen the results of the bandwidthTest quoted in several papers and then used to measure the efficiency of code, where the bandwidth of the author's code is measured using the SI format. It may have been designed for educational purposes, but it's being used as a benchmark. I guess that's the author's fault for not checking the benchmark though...